# Sum of the array values and display them on page

Tags: php, arrays

I want to simple sum the array doubled values and display the total sum of each value. My array looks like this

```
Array ( 
      [0] => 1 
      [1] => 1 
      [2] => 2 
      [3] => 1 
      [4] => 3 
)
```

The output should be
`3,1,1` because `1*3`, `2*1` and `3*1`. So far I've the array out.

```
$sum = Points::all();

foreach ($sum as $item) {
      $data = json_decode($item->points, true);
      $point_ids[] = key($data);
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($point_ids).'</pre>';
```

Comment: So, basically, you are looking for the number of occurrence of each value ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_count_values()

```
$result = array_count_values($input);
```

This Function does exactly what you ask for. The Output of this Function is an Array where the (distinct) Keys are the Values of the Input Array and the Values are the Sums of the Occurrence.

You can output the Values and Sums afterwards this Way:

```
foreach($result as $value => $sum){
 echo $value.': '.$sums.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how I missed it. Got it to work. Excuse me but I'm very new in this. Thank you again!

Comment: I added it to my Answer! Dont mix up the Variable Names. In your Case $input is your $sum.. so you better rename it.